# Wildfly DistributableSession Cache

Tags: java, spring, wildfly, infinispan, spring-session

Is it safe to store references to an HttpSession in an HashMap?
I have a Spring application deployed in Wildfly 10.1 with  in the web.xml. The HttpSessions that are created are org.wildfly.clustering.web.undertow.session.DistributableSession which I believe is indirectly stored in a distributed Infinispan cache.

Right now all I am looking to do is update the last access time after Websocket pings. Ideally I would be using Spring Sessions, which has this functionality built in, but I don't see an easy way to integrate Spring Session 2.0.3 with the built in Infinispan 8.2.4.

Comment: why not access infinispan directly? do you mean httpsession or javax.websocket.Session

Comment: HttpSession. It doesn't appear that the HttpSession object itself is cached in infinispan, but various parts of the data are stored in there with custom key objects.

Comment: From what I understand, Spring Session can be used as an alternative way to store HTTP session implementation in application server. I would use either one or the other, but not both.